# f.input collect: is showing duplicates in the select

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, simple-form

I have the following simple_form input:

```
<%= f.input :user_id, collection: [options_for_select(User.all.map{ |u| [u.firstname, u.id]})] %>
```

There are 3 users in my local database. When I use the select in the form it shows the users twice like: 
Tony 
Johnny
Bill
Tony
Johnny
Bill

I'm not a pro with the map syntax above, so it may have to do with that.

Comment: u can use .uniq method to avoid duplication

Comment: I actually already tried that and it doesn't work. Even if it did, I'm curious why the users are being duplicated. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I found this as a much better way to code the select. Also, the one I was trying above doesn't work on Heroku. This is what I used to make it work:

true) %>